# 'BEGIN' expected but 'USES' found

Tags: freepascal

Hi I've done these lines of code on freepascal:

```
type bigNum=string;
function bigMod(a:bigNum;b:longint):longint;
var i,hold:longint;
begin
hold:=0;
for i:=1 to length(a) do
    hold:=(ord(a[i])-48+hold*10)mod b;
    bigMod:=hold;
end;
uses sysutils;
var a,i,n:longint;
begin
readln(n);
a:=1;
for i:=1 to n-2 do
    a:=a*2;
IntToStr(a);
writeln(bigMod(bigMod(a,n),1000000000));
end.
```

but when I run it, it said 'BEGIN' expected but 'USES' found,
what should I do to fix it? if i change 'BEGIN' on top of 'USES' its will be another error

Comment: Please, do not put code at an off-site location (that cannot be reached in this case). Edit your question and insert the code here. But before you do that, strip the code down to a minimal, just small enough to express the error.

Comment: when I tried to give codes in here it somehow said that some of I aren't actual codes but when I put on free pascal it said errors

Comment: Without code, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. Also, read the error message. What do you think it means, and what does that imply for how to understand the problem.

Comment: If you can't provide a [mcve] it's best that you remove this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uses` clause must appear after the (optional) `program` statement, but before any other statement. Move the `uses` clause to the top of the code, immediately after the `program` statement if indeed you have one.

Comment: Can you answer my other problem please? when i do your answer actually i worked but there is an 'IntToString' code block but why it still says it expected 'ShortString'? I thought that code would change identifier a from longInt to ShortString

Comment: IntToStr is a function. It returns a string. It can't change the type of a variable. It doesn't modify its argument.

Comment: So can you change the type of a variable?

Comment: No, you cannot change the type of a variable. You declared `a` to be `longint` and it is `longint` forever. When you call `IntToStr`, it is a function that returns a `string` containing the decimal representation of the integer that you passed as argument to the function.

Comment: Sorry to make you feel annoying and drive this question to a whole new question but what can i do to fix it? You see bigNum is in string so 'a' needs to be in string too for the function but when i do that its impossible now to do 'a:=a*2' i don't think ord() and chr() will work because number would be too big to do chr()

Comment: You can use more than one variable. And these variables don't have to have the same type. Think about that and see if you can solve the problem.